# Loop with dictionaries in python

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I'm stuck on making a loop. I'd like to input the first key in the Teacher1 dict and it's corresponding value into my payload dictionary and run my code on the payload dict. Then the next item in the students dict would be inputted into the payload dict and run till I go through all the values in the students dict. Thanks for your time!

```
Teacher1 = {'Username1': 'Pass1', 'Username2: 'Pass2...}

Payload = {'User_id': 'Username1', : 'Password': 'Pass1' }
```

Comment: please post some code so we can see what you have so far

Answer (score 1):

You can just loop over the keys of the dictionary

```
payload = {}
for user_id in teacher1:
  payload['User_id'] = user_id
  payload['Password'] = teacher1[user_id]
  # Do some processing with payload here
```

Comment: Also the `.keys()` is unnecessary, you can just say `for user_id in Teacher1`

Comment: @TehTris Yikes, not sure what I was thinking there :)

Comment: @Cyber thanks, I started with that, couldn't remember if it worked and tossed in keys to be safe.  Then apparently blew the syntax anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `update` to update a dictionary with values from another dictionary...

```
>>> d1 = {'a':'b'}
>>> d2 = {'c':'d'}
>>> d1.update(d2)
>>> d1
{'c': 'd', 'a': 'b'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
for k, v in Teacher1.items():
  Payload = {}
  Payload['User_id'] = k
  Payload['Password'] = v
  # do payload processing
```

Comment: It looks like you have confused Python's dict access syntax with Perl's (or another language's).  Also, comments in Python are `#`, not `//`.